# Updating 180k rows via MySQL stored procedure & function is too slow - how to speed up

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ST`@`%` PROCEDURE `CalculateCheapestPriceALL`()
    BEGIN

        UPDATE 
            tickets  
        SET 
            tickets.Cheapest = GetCheapestTicket(tickets.STPerformerID, tickets.STVenueID, tickets.FeedID);

    END
```

The function GetCheapestTicket is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`suprtickets`@`%` FUNCTION `GetCheapestTicket`(performerID INT(11), venueID INT(11), feedID INT(11)) RETURNS decimal(10,2)
BEGIN

    DECLARE TicketPrice DECIMAL(10,2);

    SET TicketPrice = 

    IFNULL((
    SELECT 
        MIN(tickets.Price)
    FROM 
        tickets
    WHERE 
        tickets.STPerformerID = performerID
    AND
        tickets.STVenueID = venueID
    AND 
        tickets.FeedID = feedID
    AND 
        tickets.Price > 0
    ),0);

    RETURN TicketPrice;

END
```

Running the stored procedure currently takes about 10 minutes, and I'm looking for ways to speed this up.

The following image shows a sample of the data:[image: SQL data example]

The idea behind the stored procedure is to find the cheapest price for the same STPerformerID and STVenueID, and then update this in the Cheapest column. So then I can quickly look up the lowest price for each peformer and venue.

There are about 20k individual Perfomers, and a similar amount of Venues.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are running the query to find the lowest price over again for *every* row, which is very inefficient.

If you combine the two queries into one query. it will execute significantly faster:

```
UPDATE tickets AS t1
JOIN (SELECT STPerformerID, STVenueID, STFeedID, MIN(Price) AS cheapest
      FROM tickets
      WHERE Price > 0
      GROUP BY STPerformerID, STVenueID, STFeedID) AS t2
USING (STPerformerID, STVenueID, STFeedID)
SET t1.Price = t2.cheapest
```

To make it perform well, make sure you have a composite index on `(STPerformerID, STVenueID, STFeedID)` (or at least some subset of these columns).

Comment: Brilliant! That works perfect.  Just ran it and it took around 15 seconds, which is a huge improvement. Upvoted and accepted.